# Capturar JSON com entidades aninhadas em C#

Tags: c#, json

Preciso mapear esta json para dentro de meus objetos C# onde criei conforme a estrutura da json

**JSON**:

[image: json]

**Classe root**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sub classes**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao rodar o código o objeto "intraday" na linha 21 vem nulo.
Vejam que no caso do objeto "json_data" na linha 19 desserializa normalmente, já que é dinâmico e não estou mapeando para classe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegue editar sua pergunta colocando o JSON e as classes modelos em código? com imagem fica difícil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que o JSON tá com um números, espaços e pontos nas chaves.

Exemplo:

```
...
    "Time Series (60min)":{
        ...
        "2021-10-07 17:00:00":{
            "1. open" : "141.8100",
            ...
        }   
    }
}
```

Repare que entre as aspas duplas (") das chaves tem algo a mais do que os nomes das suas propriedades.

Uma chave

```
"1. open": "141.8100"
```

não vai ser mapeada de forma direta para uma propriedade

```
public string open { get; set; }
```

e você não pode criar uma propriedade com o nome `1. open`

Para resolver o seu problema você tem algumas opções.
Mapear para a variavel e usa o REGEX para tirar os "." e espaços para a chave ficar.

```
"open": "141.8100"
```

E dai o mapeamento para seu objeto vai funcionar.

Outras abordagens como sobrescrever o `Resolver` ou algo do gênero são mais complicadas e dura mais tempo para arrumar. De modo rápido, criar um método para tratar o JSON de retorno e arrumar as chaves antes de mapear seria o mais rápido e eficiente para fazer (Eu acho hahaha)